# street addres parsing problem.. pease help me with this

Tags: c#

1. The Context
   While doing any online transaction the address of the user is mandatory. Rather than entering street name, locality, State etc, as separate fields, the better way to get the address is that you can ask the user to enter the complete address in one field. What the merchant will require would be the exact address with different fields like street, locality, city, zip code etc.
2. The Problem
   You will be given an address in a string, you need to parse the address from the string and return the structure Address.

Signature: Address parseAddress(String address)
Input: String with address(e.g. “Lunkad Tower, 6th floor, \r\n Viman Nagar, \r\n Pune 411014")
Output: The structure Address

```
public class Address  
{  
    public string Street {get;set;};  // Lunkad Tower, 6th floor  
    public string Locality {get;set;};  // Viman Nagar  
    public string City {get;set;};  // Pune  
    public string State {get;set;};  // MH, Maharashtra  
    public string PostalCode {get;set;}; // 60611  
    public string Country {get;set;};  // e.g. India, IN  
}
```

Expected Output:
We want your application to parse all the given addresses in the attached input file. The output should be in a text file containing all the parsed addresses, where each parsed output address is in the following format:

```
Street|Locality|City|State|PostalCode|Country
```

Each address output should be in a new line. 
In case any of the address field is missing, leave the space blank between the “|” (pipe) separators. Don’t remove the pipe separators.   
For example, if State is not mentioned in the input string, the output should be:

```
Street|Locality|City| |PostalCode|Country
```

Comment: It's C# from the {get;set;}. Asking a homework question without even attempting doesn't get good responses.

Comment: This looks like it's copied & pasted straight out either a homework assignment or a requirements document. Either way, it's not a proper question in the current form. Please use proper formatting, tag it as homework if it applies and ask a specific question. Also include what you already came up with to solve your problem and why it didn't work. Also: What is up with the Java,C++ and C tags when you include automatic properties, a C# feature?

Comment: Do parsing based on delimiter as comma(,) Then you can get all the sub-strings. You can fill the structure with those.

Comment: Don't do this, it's highly error-prone and it doesn't give much benefit to have a single field only. Even systems with a *huge* database of valid addresses behind such as Google Maps can't get this right all the time. Use separate fields, you won't be able to parse all creative variations of writing addresses that users might come up with. Besides, it is the de-facto standard to use separate fields for this, so usability will also benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to create a simple Finite State machine or just a big if statement, look for splits on ',' and purge any \r\n. For the postcode look for a number near the City. Your teacher has made this task simple for you with the additional \r\n separators.

At least attempt the question.